# C# - Insert null into SQL Compact Edition table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

Iam trying to insert some data into a SQL Compact Edition table using parameter. My table allows null to be inserted but when I run my code below I can not get it working because one of these paramerters is going to be null sometimes and I would like to insert null into that column when the paramerter is null.

What how can I fix this?

```
string strConn = Properties.Settings.Default.SqlConnectionString;


        using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(strConn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into table(ID, Name, Adress) values (@parm1, @parm2, @param3)", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm1", ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm2", Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm3", Adress);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Or does it simply not work?

Comment: When the value parameter value is null it says that the parameter has not been set.

Comment: Seems to me that it should work.  Want is the problem.

Comment: There is no problem when the all the paramerters has values, but one of them is null I get error that says the paramerter has not been set.

Comment: One of the parameters in the SQL query string is named @param3. You set @parm1 through @parm3. Maybe this is the issue?

Answer (score 8):

I think you can pass `DBNull.Value` as your value when it is null:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm2", (Name as object) ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: But you need to cast either Name or DBNull.Value to object (c# compiler doesn't do this for you)

Comment: when I try this I get Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: I thought DBNull is a class and so can pass as an object... but you're probably right in that I can't use ?? on two sides with different types.

Comment: `x ?? y` is really a shorthand for `x ? x : y`.  Both x and y must be the same types or the compiler will complain.  I'll try casting the name as an object to see.

Comment: @Stephen - Probably just a typo, but it's `x!=null ? x : y`. It's a check for null, not a bool-check.

Comment: @Hans, correct!  Have been programming in JavaScript too long lately...  :-(  Need to get back to some good old C# work!

Answer (score 4):

Check to see if your parameter == null, and if so, either insert DBNull in place of it or omit the parameter.

.NET nulls and SQL nulls are different.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the source of this problem is located in the SQL query string itself.
You declare three parameters:

`@parm1`, `@parm2` and - focus on the spelling - `@param3`

And you set:
`@parm1`, `@parm1` and - focus on the spelling - `@parm3`

My guess is that the whole `@parm3` vs. `@param3` parameter naming could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I use following extension method for setting nullable parameters.

```
public static class SqlExtensions
    {
        public static void AddNullableParameterWithValue(this SqlCeCommand cmd, string name, object value)
        {
            if (null != value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, value);
            else
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, DBNull.Value);
        }
    }
```